# Как сделать скроллбар у класса, убрав его с body html?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

У меня есть страничка сайта, на которой я разместил заголовок и часть с контентом. Как видно на скриншоте, скроллбар справа находится не в части с контентом (черной), а на `body` или `html` (не знаю). Как сделать так, чтобы скроллбар находился под заголовком?

[image]

Попробовал в html документе сделать такую структуру страницы:

```
<body>

    <div class="main__header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="main.html"><img src="logo_w3s.gif"></a>
                    <a class="nav__link active" href="#">Info</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="news.html">News</a>
                    <a class="nav__link" href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#">≡</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main__field">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="section">
                <div class="section__inner">
                    <div class="section__title">Dear</div>
                    <div class="section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt facere
                        nesciunt, unde dignissimos laboriosam quibusdam debitis id libero eaque veritatis! Nostrum
                        maiores distinctio eaque ipsam ipsa labore, assumenda quo dolorem.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="section">
                <div class="section__inner">
                    <div class="section__title">Dear</div>
                    <div class="section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt facere
                        nesciunt, unde dignissimos laboriosam quibusdam debitis id libero eaque veritatis! Nostrum
                        maiores distinctio eaque ipsam ipsa labore, assumenda quo dolorem.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

То есть создать класс под заголовок и под контент. И с помощью css'a спрятать скроллбар у `body` и сделать его у `main__field`. Спрятать получилось с помощью

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Но в `main__field` скроллбара не появилось.

То есть я хочу, чтобы заголовок был во всю ширину страницы. Как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно спрятать основной скроллбар

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Потом просто добавить его в элемент с контентом

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background: #74e6cf;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #ccc;
}

.element {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Немного неполный ответ. Скроллбар появляется там, где я хочу, но он, почему-то, состоит только из трека, без самого скролла (само пролистывание страницы работает).

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Точно, нужно же в `.element` добавить `max-height`.